# Nodejs - this.on is not a function event emitter object inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance, eventemitter

I'm learning how to use event emitter and inheritance in nodejs. I get the error:

```
TypeError: this.on is not a function
```

My code:

```js
const EventEmitter = require('events')

const Emitter = function () {
    EventEmitter.call(this)

    this.on('event',value => {
        console.log('Event emitted',value)
    })
}

const myEmitter = new Emitter()
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: To inherit from EventEmitter your Emitter class needs to inherit it's prototype: `Emitter.prototype = new EventEmitter()`

Answer (score 2):

With above code you're not actually inheriting from `EventEmitter`. I'd just use an actual class that `extends` it:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events')

class Emitter extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.on('event', value => {
            console.log('Event emitted', value)
        });
    }
}

const myEmitter = new Emitter();
myEmitter.emit('event', 'hello'); // logs 'Event emitted hello' to the console.
```

Comment: I saw a npm package that used the event emitter as my code. So, it's just possible to do it with class?

Comment: Sure you can. Maybe you want to read this nice tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/using-event-emitters-in-node-js

Comment: Yep, read that before doing my code, but I want to figure out how to do it without a class.

Comment: You don't actually need to create a subclass, you can just instantiate the emitter directly:

`const eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();` and then use it like e.g. `eventEmitter.on(...);` or `eventMitter.emit(...)`